# How to change include dirs, library dirs and libraries with CLion

Tags: clion

In CLion, how can I specify the include directories where the C++ compiler will look for header files? Also, how do I setup the libraries to link against, and their library directories?

Currently I'm doing those tasks modifying directly the file `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
include_directories(/opt/netcdf/include)
link_directories(/opt/netcdf/lib)
link_libraries(netcdf)
```

But I wonder if it is possible to accomplish the same thing using the GUI.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

In CLion, the `CMakeLists.txt` file(s) for your project are the [system of record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_record) for your build system and settings.  What's shown in the GUI is derived from the build script.  This is similar to the way IntelliJ uses a Maven `pom.xml` file as the system of record for a Java build and shows things in the IDE based on the file.  Based on my past experience with IntelliJ, I expect that JetBrains will make this a more bidirectional experience (updating the GUI will edit the `CMakeLists.txt`) over time.